# How to lazyload images in BLOGGER (blogspot) without using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, lazy-loading, blogger

I donot use jQuery in my blogger template. Is there a way to implement automatic lazy loading or defering of images without using jQuery? Or using some lightweight scripts like https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazyload/2.0.3/lazyload-min.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to :

- Go to the Blogger dashboard and click on the theme section.
- Then click on Edit HTML from the drop-down menu.
- On the HTML Editor click on `Ctrl + F` and search for `</body>`  or
  scroll down to the end you will find this `</body>` tag.
- Paste the javascript code just above the `</body>` tag and save it
- Please note put the Below code in `<script>`  `</script>`

  ```
   //<![CDATA[

   (function(a){a.fn.lazyload=function(b){var c={threshold:0,failurelimit:0,event:"scroll",effect:"show",container:window};if(b){a.extend(c,b)}var d=this;if("scroll"==c.event){a(c.container).bind("scroll",function(b){var e=0;d.each(function(){if(a.abovethetop(this,c)||a.leftofbegin(this,c)){}else if(!a.belowthefold(this,c)&&!a.rightoffold(this,c)){a(this).trigger("appear")}else{if(e++>c.failurelimit){return false}}});var f=a.grep(d,function(a){return!a.loaded});d=a(f)})}this.each(function(){var b=this;if(undefined==a(b).attr("original")){a(b).attr("original",a(b).attr("src"))}if("scroll"!=c.event||undefined==a(b).attr("src")||c.placeholder==a(b).attr("src")||a.abovethetop(b,c)||a.leftofbegin(b,c)||a.belowthefold(b,c)||a.rightoffold(b,c)){if(c.placeholder){a(b).attr("src",c.placeholder)}else{a(b).removeAttr("src")}b.loaded=false}else{b.loaded=true}a(b).one("appear",function(){if(!this.loaded){a("<img />").bind("load",function(){a(b).hide().attr("src",a(b).attr("original"))[c.effect](c.effectspeed);b.loaded=true}).attr("src",a(b).attr("original"))}});if("scroll"!=c.event){a(b).bind(c.event,function(c){if(!b.loaded){a(b).trigger("appear")}})}});a(c.container).trigger(c.event);return this};a.belowthefold=function(b,c){if(c.container===undefined||c.container===window){var d=a(window).height()+a(window).scrollTop()}else{var d=a(c.container).offset().top+a(c.container).height()}return d<=a(b).offset().top-c.threshold};a.rightoffold=function(b,c){if(c.container===undefined||c.container===window){var d=a(window).width()+a(window).scrollLeft()}else{var d=a(c.container).offset().left+a(c.container).width()}return d<=a(b).offset().left-c.threshold};a.abovethetop=function(b,c){if(c.container===undefined||c.container===window){var d=a(window).scrollTop()}else{var d=a(c.container).offset().top}return d>=a(b).offset().top+c.threshold+a(b).height()};a.leftofbegin=function(b,c){if(c.container===undefined||c.container===window){var d=a(window).scrollLeft()}else{var d=a(c.container).offset().left}return d>=a(b).offset().left+c.threshold+a(b).width()};a.extend(a.expr[":"],{"below-the-fold":"$.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0, container: window})","above-the-fold":"!$.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0, container: window})","right-of-fold":"$.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0, container: window})","left-of-fold":"!$.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0, container: window})"})})(jQuery);$(function(){$("img").lazyload({placeholder:"https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-XNnCtsmVWps/WwUzI4O3OMI/AAAAAAAAGzM/s5IzNI42txMh8ZglfGk9ktfD7CqQ0JkMgCLcBGAs/s1600/sun.gif",effect:"fadeIn",threshold:"-50"})});
   //]]>
  ```

Note: For more details refer this [Website](https://www.techyleaf.in/2020/10/how-to-enable-lazy-loading-on-blogger.html)

Answer (score 0):

Partially yes, there is. You can use native lazy-load for images and iframes.

```
<img src="..." loading="lazy" width="200" height="200">
```

This works on Chrome 77+ and chrome based browsers.

Check for more details here: [Native lazy-loading for the web](https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading)